# issue in setting cell value by row and column after merge in phpexcel

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

I want to merge 1st `row A1 to H1` and input category 1 and `merge I1 to P1` and input category 2 as values. I am trying with this below code and it is merging columns which is fine but it is not inputting second category value.

what is wrong here?

```
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "NetApp Nominator's Contact Information");        
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:H1');

    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, "NetApp manoj");        
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('I1:P1');
```

Am using phpexcel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because column `1` is column `B`, and column `B` no longer exists in row `1`, it's part of the group of cells that you've merged (`A1:H1`), and now only the top-leftmost cell of the merge group exists.... there's no column `C` or `D` or `E` or `H` any more in row `1`.... the next column that exists in row `1` is column `I`.

Merging cells makes all but the top-left cell of the merge group inaccessible; but doesn't make them non-existent

Assuming that you're trying to store the second value in column `I`, then that's column number `8`, so

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(8, 1, "NetApp manoj");
```